# UIwebview filetype on clicking

Tags: ios, uiwebview, download, hyperlink

I have a link containing excel file in gmail which i open in safari browser of ios device .
I want to open  my application when i click on the link and download that file to the application document directory . 
is it possible ? 
if so please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you should register the supported type with ios, in your case a excel file

read more @ https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1

Comment: thanks for your response but i tried to change the info.plist but i got a parse error